# Setting an immutable object equal to something

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Label has a property call attributedText,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSAttributedString *attributedText;
```

This attributed string is not mutable. So to modify it, you must make a mutable copy.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *labelText= [myLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
[labelText setAttributes:...];
myLabel.attributedText = labelText;
```

Someone please explain what's happening behind the scene in memory during this process.

myLabel.attributedText is a pointer that points to an attributedText object in memory, which has already been allocated and initialized.

Next, you're making a copy of that object and setting *labelText to point to this object in memory.

So you next modify the object that labelText points to by using the setAttributes method.

But what happens on the last line? Are we just setting myLabel.attributedText to point to the same object that labelText points to in memory?

If so, once this whole thing goes out of scope, *labelText get set to nil but the object that it points to stays in memory because myLabel.attributedText still points to it, keeping the retain count at 1.

Does ARC just automatically release the old object that myLabel.attributedText points to initially?

How did people release that object pre-ARC?

Does ARC always know to set the labelText pointer to nil when the function goes out of scope?

So the way to keep an object alive when it goes out of scope is to set a property with strong pointer to point to this object? Are local pointers always set to nil when it goes out of scope?

EDIT: I also did not notice that you're setting an NSattributedString pointer to point to an NSMutableAttributedString object. The Stanford Lecture note had a typo. If you did make this mistake in your code though, it would still compile and run right?

Comment: Before ARC you didn't care about the object stored in property. You had to care only about that you allocated instance using `mutableCopy` and had to release this ownership. Just with `[labelText release]` at the end.

Comment: It's very critical that you understand the difference between an object and a pointer to an object.  It sounds like you're getting there but don't quite have it yet.

Comment: Hot Licks, do you know any resource that can help me learn more about this? I want to understand all the subtleties that goes on behind the scene but unfortunately most lectures never explain. Right now it just feels like I know enough to be dangerous.

Comment: I'm afraid any books I have are 30-40 years old.  But a good lecturer would spend several sessions on the concept, then come back to it several times, to hammer home the significance.  (It may actually help to learn machine/assembly language, to know what's "below" the stuff you see in higher-level languages.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the property is defined with a `strong` modifier, it means that on assignment, the system retains the assigned `labelText`, so it will not be released once the method returns.

Remember, objects are allocated on the heap, so they are unaffected by a method going out of scope. With ARC, unused objects are automatically released for you. Since the property in your example is `strong`, the object is retained and the system will not deallocate it.

This works with a mutable object, since `NSMutableAttributedString` inherits from `NSAttributedString` (it is a subclass). Read more here: [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

It is important to notice, that `attributedText` is defined differently than in your code example:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
```

Notice that the modifier here is `copy` instead of `retain`.

What would actually happen is the mutable object would be **copied** to another instance, which would be retained by the label, while your mutable attributed string would be released right after the assignment.

`copy` is used instead of `strong` to make sure the value passed upon setting `attributedText` remains immutable.

Comment: The difference between `strong` and `copy` is not _so_ important in this case, since the memory semantics are the same.

Comment: I'm trying to understand more about how the compiler treats pointers and actual objects. Let us pretend that in the first example, myLabel.attributedText is strong, would I be correct in saying that by the time the function goes out of scope, there would be 2 pointers pointing to the attributed string object? The local pointer labelText would not be released? In the second example where the property copy, you're making a copy of the attributed string (which was also a copy originally) when you set myLabel.attributedText  to point to it ?

Comment: @iMartin Yes, I only added the note on the `copy` to further explain.

Comment: Also, in the last line, if we just set myLabel.attributedText to point to an attributed string object. How does this work? Because this object is mutable. You're setting an immutable pointer to point to a mutable object. Is this the reason why the property is copy instead of strong?

Comment: @user3142893 Don't think of it in terms of pointers, think of it in terms of who is retaining the object and when. In the first example (`strong`), the object is retained first after creation, and then it is retained again after setting it in the label's property. Once the method ends, the local retain is released, but the label still retains. So the object lives.

Comment: @user3142893 If `copy` is used, the only retain is in the local method, so when that goes out, the object is released and since no one else is retaining, it is dealloced.

Comment: @user3142893 It works because NSMutableAttributedString inherits from NSAttributedString. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming for more info. Updated the answer with this information.

Comment: When the property is copy, when `myLabel.attributedText=labelText` , right there you're copying the object and it's retain by myLabel.attributedText right? So before labelText gets release, it got copied ?

Comment: @user3142893 Yes. It implements the `NSCopying` protocol, which defines a `copy` method. This method returns an immutable copy of the object. **The copy is retained rather than `labelText`**.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the help. There are so many subtleties like this that video lecture just doesn't cover.

Comment: @user3142893 If this has answered your question, please accept.